# div window should be on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show tooltip window or div on the top the icon... I have not fixed the height. If the text more than four lines it covers the cross icon...
[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbqtv/)

[image]

```
    /*--Tooltip Styles--*/
    .tip_trigger{display:block; padding:6px;}
    .tip {
        color: #333;
        background:#ffffff;
        border:1px solid #747474;
        display:none; /*--Hides by default--*/
        padding:10px;
        margin-left:-143px;
        margin-top:-50px;
        text-align:left; line-height:16px;
        position:absolute;  z-index:1000;
        cursor:auto;
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #D3D3D3;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #D3D3D3;box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #D3D3D3;
    }   

 /*--jQuery --*/

     $(document).ready(function () {
            //Tooltips
            $(".tip_trigger").hover(function () {
                tip = $(this).find('.tip');
                tip.show(); //Show tooltip
            }, function () {
                tip.hide(); //Hide tooltip        
            })

        });

/*  HTML:- --------*/

    <td>
     <a class="tip_trigger">
      <img src="http://cdn-img.easyicon.cn/png/5249/524975.png" />
      <span class="tip" style="width: 250px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet enim...</span>
    </a>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure is it what you are looking for, but who knows:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sbqtv/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                //Tooltips
                $(".tip_trigger").hover(function () {
                    tip = $(this).find('.tip');
                    tip.show().css('margin-top',-tip.height()); //Show tooltip
                }, function () {
                    tip.hide(); //Hide tooltip          
                })

            });​
```

Comment: can we move the tip div window a little up.. Currently div covers half the icon...

Comment: Thanks again.. Can we add margin-top class on it.. I need to give some more top margin...:)

Comment: You can do something like that: -(tip.outerHeight()+40)    '40' or whatever you need

Answer (score 1):

Here you have what you are looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/Sbqtv/7/

I added the `position:relative` property at your `.tip_trigger` and then i added the `bottom` and `right` properties at the `.tip` class. (Taking into considerations the image height and width)

You have to work with relative positions (top, bottom, left, right) because you dont know which will be the height of the tip. Don't use margins:

```
.tip_trigger{
    display:block;
    padding:6px; 
    position:relative;
}
.tip {
    color: #333;
    background:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #747474;
    display:none; /*--Hides by default--*/
    padding:10px;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:16px;
    bottom:50px;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;    z-index:1000;
    cursor:auto;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #D3D3D3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #D3D3D3;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #D3D3D3;
}
```

​

But there's another problem when the tip of one of the bottom images hides the top image.